# XSLT not displaying data from Arabic column external list

Tags: 2013, xslt, external-list

I have an external list named "users". It is coming from SQL Server and has following two columns:

> English_Name varchar(300)
>   Arabic_Name nvarchar(300)

Notice the Arabic_Name field has data type nvarchar.

I am trying to display the names of users on page using XSLT as follows:

This one displays English name

```
<xsl:value-of select="@English_Name">
```

This one doesn't display Arabic name and just shows blank

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Arabic_Name">
```

How to show Arabic names?

When I open this external list in "Site Contents" I can see that it contain data and is showing both English and Arabic names but when I try to display Arabic name using XSLT, it doesn't display anything. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok my bad. I forgot to add the column "Arabic_Name" in current view.